# Android Developing - Compile OK, crashes at runtime

Tags: java, android, crash, switch-statement, toast

I'm very new to developing. I'm building simple android apps as training. Please, consider the following code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu0:
            MenuItem input0 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.menu0);
            String string0 = input0.getTitle().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, string0,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu1:
            MenuItem input1 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.menu0);
            String string1 = input1.getTitle().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, string1,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The aim of this method is to show which one of the two elements of a menu have been pressed by the user, by means of a toast composed by the text contained in the menu elements (as I said, this is just for training ;) ).

The compiler of Android Studio (3.1.2 on Windows) exit with green light (no errors), the apk can be installed on real device but the app crashes (destroyed) when one of the elements of the menu are pressed.

If I change `string0` and `string1` with an hard coded String, say:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Settings",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

the app runs correctly.

Do you have any idea about the reason of this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: can you add crash logs?

Comment: what are input0 and input1? EditTexts?

Comment: Post your crash log

Comment: They contain MenuItem defined in res\menu\mainmenu.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu0"
        android:title="@string/menu_options" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:title="@string/menu_share" />
</menu>`

Comment: @MashukKhan OK, let me Google how to get the crash log from an Android OS and revert.

Comment: Try pressing Alt+6 on Windows or CMD+6 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because it tries to make and show a toast with null content. Either the findViewById isn't finding the element at all, or the getTitle() isn't getting anything, that's way a hard coded string works.